# How do I make a button create a text document with the content of a form in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, button

(I made a form using Java swing. But Im stuck on the "submit" Button. The button is supposed to create a text document on the desktop including all the things answered in the form. How do I do that?)

The document should have the Employees name as name, and then have this layout:

- Name:
- Telephone number:
- Email-address:
- Address:
- Gender:
- Occupation:
- Salary:
- Is Manager: Yes/No

edit: Sorry for posting my whole code, I edited in the relevant part. This is what I have right now. I don't know how to put a textfield's content as the file name or how to put text into the file.

This is my code:

```
JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            File EmployeeFile = new File("C:/Users/Nicol/Desktop/Employeesname.txt");
              if(!EmployeeFile.exists())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        boolean HasBeenCreated = EmployeeFile.createNewFile();
                        if(HasBeenCreated)
                        {
                            System.out.println("A new employee has been added succesfully! Their detail-file has been created on the desktop.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("An error occured. Employee's file has not been created.");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

Comment: *"How do I do that?"* So .. what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? *"I used a Windowbuilder for this, if that is any relevant."* Not in the slightest. Tips: Break the problem down and start small. First try creating a `File` and writing a single `String` to it. That should take less than 20 lines of code. If you run into problems, post a [mcve] and ask an explicit question, rather than dumping over 160 lines of code with custom (3rd party) imports. Now .. which of 3 different close reasons is most relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to create a text file with the format you want

```
try
{
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("file_location"+".txt"));   
 fw.write(
 "Name : "            +"\n"+
 "Telephone Number : "+"\n"+
 "Email-Address : "   +"\n"+
 "Address : "         +"\n"+
 "Gender : "          +"\n"+
 "Occupation : "      +"\n"+
 "Salary : "          +"\n"+
 "Is Manager : "      +"\n"+
 );
 fw.close();
}
catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
```